# Backbone.js/Handlebars button click event not firing

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, handlebars.js

I have a Handlerbar that has a button, like this:

```
<button id="addLine" type="image" class="AddButtonClass" title="Add New Line" onclick = "addNewBlock('{{blockId}}');"></button>
```

I then use this template to create objects dynamically, like this:

```
    var template = window.app.getTemplate('myHandlebar');       
    var budgetBlock = $(template({blockId: guid}));  
    $("#BudgetTable tbody").append(budgetBlock);
```

I then have a function like this:

```
addNewBlock: function(getId){
    alert(getId);
},
```

The problem is that the button on the Handlebar event never fires.  Instead, I get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: addNewBlock is not defined "

Why cant I assign an onclick event to a button in the handlebars?  Is there a way to add an event to a button, dynamically, when the template is created?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead:

```
<button id="addLine" type="image" class="AddButtonClass" title="Add New Line" data-id="{{blockId}}"></button>
```

and in your backbone for example in your initialize function:

```
$('#addLine').click(function(){
    alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```

or you can create an event in backbone

```
events: {
 'click #addLine' : 'addNewBlock'

},
addNewBlock: function(e){
     console.log( $(e.currentTarget).data("id"));
}
```

Comment: I was kind of hoping to have a way to do it in Handlebars, but your first solution does the trick as well.  Thanks!